# How to animate front-end representation smoothly based on real-time data?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, real-time

We are going to develop an HTML5+CSS+JavaScript web application based on real-time data.

The data is recorded in an .csv file and we retrieve the lastest record by using `setInterval()` to trigger an AJAX call. Currently, the project is implemented on an Apache server without using any databases. When we are trying to draw some animation graphs based on such kind of data by CSS/SVG/JavaScript, the animations usually interrupted by the update of data and the transitions are not smoothly.

For example, we try to use the JavaScript library [SiriWave](https://github.com/caffeinalab/siriwavejs) to draw a curve on the front page and the wave is interrupted when the data is updated by the `setInterval()` function. Is there any way to update the curve smoothly without using a timer refreshing? My code is here:

```
function getData(limit, callback) {
    var data = setInterval(function () {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': "../data/data.csv?t="+new Date().getTime(),
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        var count = json.replace(/[^\n]/g, '').length;
        var i = count - 1;
        var lines = json.split("\n");
        var items = lines[i].split(",");
        callback(items);
    }, limit);
}

getData(1000, function (items){
    //Used to remove the last scene
    document.getElementById("wave").innerHTML = '';
    //Start to draw the waving curve
    var siriWave = new SiriWave({
        container: document.getElementById('wave'),
        width: 1920,
        height: 400,
        speed: items[1],
        frequency: items[2],
        autostart: true
    });
});
```

Sample data is here (in csv format):

```
2016-07-20, 100, 20
2016-07-21, 120, 40
2016-07-22, 140, 60
```

The problem is that the curve changes suddenly from current state to the next updated state. Does anyone have ideas on how to solve the animation issues? Both back-end and front-end solutions are welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: This is vague. Imagine a colleague came to you and said "my animations don't work." What would you do? Probably ask to see the actual code:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I suspect you'll need to create a [mcve] with some minimal simulated data (doesn't have to be ajax loaded) so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: It seems like this is more an question of SiriWave than anything else. While I'm not familiar with it, it looks from their API that they have a setSpeed and setFrequency option. If it's implemented well, using their update methods instead of just blowing it away and creating a new one every time may do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can replace timers with sockets. There are many ways of doing this depending on your server side technologies. I particularly recommend using NodeJS, it manages many real-time issues like this very well.